# What is the maximum actuator strength allowed by physics?

Tags: experimental-physics, actuator

What is the strongest actuator (that can exert a controlled amount of force & be able to start/stop) that an infinitely advanced civilization (e.g. only limited by the laws of physics) could create, and how would it work?
The size and mass must be macroscopic (e.g. human-sized).

Comment: With a finite energy source? With or without gravity? Air resistance or perfect vacuum?

Comment: Cross-posted and Closed on the Physics stack... see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527267

Comment: I posted it here as they said on physics SE that it was related to engineering and not physics

Comment: I think take it with a vacuum, gravity and an unlimited energy source

Comment: On physics they clearly told you it would be **off topic** here -unless you did not understand what was written.

Comment: Ok. Where would I post this then?

Comment: This definitely belongs on Physics, and was only recently solved. It turns out that general relativity *requires* that there is a minimum modulus of elasticity for all matter. This effectively puts an upper bound on how much stress can be transmitted by matter. If it didn't work this way, you could run a perpetual motion machine near the horizon of a rotating black hole and extract power from the black hole's momentum. The limit happens to be precisely the modulus that makes that an impossible task. This was a longstanding paradox in GR.

Comment: Alright thanks, but is there an exact figure for the strength limit of an actuator with human size/mass?

Comment: And how would such an actuator work?

Comment: Metastable isomers are the plug-in-hybrid version of an H-bomb. The best are about 10% as powerful, but can be recharged if you can find the pieces.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Engineering is the art of working within constraints. When you start asking about "infinitely advanced civilizations" with "unlimited energy", you've left the arena of Engineering. Indeed, this question is better suited for [Physics.SE] or, more likely, [Worldbuilding.SE].

Answer (score 1):

You can make an actuator arbitrarily (e.g. infinitely) strong providing you make it big enough, and this would be equivalent to using an arbitrarily large number of regular strength actuators, in parallel.

If you want that force limited to a specific area, instead of spreading it as wide as needed, your one hard limit comes from general relativity. Your energy density (as output of the actuator), converted to its mass equivalent (according to $E=mc^2$) must not exert gravitational force resulting in collapse into a black hole.

There will be more other limits of engineering nature before that - e.g. if you let your actuator collapse into neutronium, it's unlikely to retain shape and function any more.

Long before that you'll exceed tensile strength of all possible materials and have it simply break, either flow or snap, although this could be overcome with using generated fields (electric, magnetic) as "materials" of its structure, bypassing common material engineering woes - although at that point your actuator ceases to be a material object and becomes a construct built from energy. It's not as sci-fi as it sounds; the entirety of "high energy side" plumbing of the VASIMR ion engine is built like that.

Note, while commonly an actuator is understood as a reusable mechanical device like a piston or a servo, the definition can be stretched quite far, and you'll find single-use pyrotechnic actuators where extreme momentary forces are required, and even currently there's nothing stopping you from basing one upon a [thermonuclear explosion](https://www.businessinsider.com/fastest-object-robert-brownlee-2016-2?IR=T).

Comment: Exactly that's what i mean like a human-sized actuator that is controllable & what is the limit to its strength?

Comment: @HamiHashmi: "Exactly that's what I mean" - what do you mean? A human sized antimatter bomb would generate about 10 exajoules of energy (~250 megatons of TNT) and it would completely evaporate everything it tries to "actuate"... unless you have a pretty sci-fi way of distributing the force, or you're propelling something like a block of neutronium.

Comment: I mean that basically what is the the maximum applicable force from a human-sized controllable actuator that is only limited by the laws of physics

Comment: and how would such an actuator work?

Comment: @HamiHashmi: Connect matter with antimatter. The resulting explosion propels the target object.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits on such forces according to physics, per se.  The limites tend to be based on strengths of materils, manufacturing capability, etc.

Archimedes said 2300 year ago,

```
 “Give me a lever long enough and a fulcrum on which to place it, and I shall move the world. ”
```

We could theoretically build an actuator that placed its fulcrum on a star, and used the energy of galaxies to move it.  The maximum actuator strength would thus be defined by what it could push against, how large it could be made, and what forces could act upon it.  With a sufficiently advanced civilization with unlimited access to resources and technology, the only limits become how much of the universe's resources and energy could be put to use in such a system.

Comment: See my comment above. It looks like we cross posted.

Comment: yes but if the actuator is human-sized (e.g. size & mass are on a human scale)

Comment: @HamiHashmi you said unlimited energy above - if you don’t know or understand what you want then we have little chance...

Comment: Yeah i mean that the power source for the actuator is unlimited-think of a battery of unlimited charge powering a motor-and the actuator is human sized